# I am trying to match numbers using regex:

Tags: regex

contain only number , hyphen and comma . 
Number between 1 to 6535
443,80,8080
4000-5000

Comment: More (and better) examples? Which language? What have you tried?

Comment: I would like to know "what would you like to check for number?". For example, number range 1 to 6535 , must start with at least one digit number and it can contain hyphen and comma, and follow at least three digit number.

Comment: So you have given two example matches: `443,80,8080` and `4000-5000`. What about `1,,2`? Or `123,`? Or `1-2-3-4-5`? Or `-123`? Please be more specific in your requirements; the question, as it currently stands, is unanswerable.

Comment: Please add a [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

i think you are asking given a string to find number using regex.

for example: (using JavaScript)

```js
a = "hi this is xxx. my mobile no is (+91)123-456-7890";

console.log( a.match(/\d.?\d+/g) );
```

regex expression is `\d.?\d+`

Comment: no, I want regex for port number. eg :- 1-65535 or 80,8080 validate in textbox

Comment: `"^((6553[0-5])|(655[0-2][0-9])|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|([0-5]{0,5})|([0-9]{1,4}))$"`                It will allow everything between 0-65535 inclusive.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by not working?

You could try something like so: `^([0-9]{1,4}|[1-5][0-9]{4}|6[0-4][0-9]{3}|65[0-4][0-9]{2}|655[0-2][0-9]|6553[0-5])$`

This will make sure that any given string is numeric and between the range of 0 and 65535.

Assuming your regular expression matches the same range, it is missing the start and end anchors (`^` and `$` respectively), so it would allow other strings besides the actual port.